# Saving selected values w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with multiple rows, each one of which contains a checkbox with item ID. The form is long and is broken into several pages.

How do I select multiple checkboxes, while going from page to page, before submitting the form?

The paging is actually done with PHP, but I do not want to submit until I am done with selection. Also, if I go back to the previous page I need to check the ones that have been previously selected.

I use jQuery on this site, so I thought it could be accomplished with it. Perhaps there's a pludin for that already?..

What's the best way to implement this feature? Thx.

Comment: If you want to give more control to client-side scripting (which I recommend), you could sent the entire form inside one web-page, and then paginate via JavaScript... This would increase visitor satisfaction since visitors would not have to wait for the server response after each step...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do that would be to submit the data to PHP and store it into session: this way it's not committed to the database but is saved across the browsing session.

This is of course because you are telling us that the different pages are generated by php so i suppose you navigate from one page to another

To that only client side you should use cookies i think. you could start [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) but i really think you should do it server side

Comment: ... or [`sessionStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute).

Comment: I would have gone with PHP, but that would require submitting the form, and I cannot submit it until I select multiple checkboxes within the form, broken into several pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use session to save the state of your checkboxes. There is a plugin for jquery "jquery.namesession" that will help you to manipulate your session variables using JS.